# The paragraph is going onto a new line after the link in HTML

Tags: html

Here are the contents of my body:

```
 <a href = "https://www.google.com" target = "__blank">Click to go to google</a>
<p>This should appear next to the link, instead of on the next line</p>
```

When I run this on my browser (chrome) it appears to show it like this

> Link to google
>
> Text

How would I make it appear on one line, paragraph after href?

Comment: What you showed IS one line, and not related to your A tag.

Comment: Sorry, corrected question

Comment: If you want the link included in the paragraph -- include it in the paragraph.

Comment: To reiterate, I want the link and the paragraph to be separate, like this: [Click to go to google](https://www.google.com) This should appear next to the link, instead of on the next line

Comment: But as of now, It is appearing on the next line. I want it on the same line. Is this default behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag p stands for paragraph. So it makes sense that the text in the p stands in a new line and fills the whole width of the parent.
By default, p has the property "display: block".

For having the text in the same row as the a we have some possibilities:

- Change the style with CSS class, via the ID or set with style = "display: inline;"

Example

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="__blank"> Click to go to google </a>
<p style="display:inline;"> This should appear next to the link, instead of the next line </p>
```

- Benefit of a different tag

Example:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com" target="__blank"> Click to go to google</a>
<span> This should appear next to the link, instead of the next line </span>
```

Comment: can i also ask, when i use a heading (h2) and then a paragraph, with the style display inline thing, it does the same thing - put on a new line. How do I go about that

Comment: h2 also has "display: block;"
"block Displays an element as a block element (like <p>). It starts on a new line, and takes up the whole width"
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: To see what the css does in your html you can use the developer tools of your browser. FF Example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools
I find it very helpful to see what kind of features are behind the tags and modify these directly in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly you should only have to include the link in the paragraph.

```
<p><a href = "https://www.google.com" target = "__blank">Click to go to google</a>
This should appear next to the link, instead of on the next line</p>
```

Comment: I want to have them separate, so the link first <a></a> then the paragraph <p></p> But ultimately I want them on 1 line.

Comment: You could of course also have them seperate and then add another <p><p/> tag around both of them...

Comment: I did that, and it is still appearing on separate lines. This [site](http://jonchretien.com/) is the one I'm trying to replicate. Scroll down to the bullet points. I checked the HTML and they appear on the same line but are separate elements ( see Spotify for Artists)

Comment: That's because they're in a list with bullet points. If you really want to reproduce that desgin you also would have to use a list

Comment: I did use a list, and it's _still_ appearing on separate lines. Try it yourself

Comment: Now I found it. If you check on the site you can see, that he uses the attribute `display : inline;` on both the link and the <p> tag. That seems to work. Please try out and then I'd change the answer if it also works for you

Answer (score 0):

This code will work fine:

```
<p>Click on <a style="display:inline;" target = "__blank" href="https://www.google.com/"> Google</a> to search anything</p>
```

Result should be like this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YubhY.png